# Approximate Minimum Feedback Arc Set implementation in Java

Tags: java, graph, implementation, approximation

I'd like to find an implementation of an approximate algorithm for the Minimum Feedback Arc Set in Java but I did not find anything so far. Does anyone have something in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the simplest approximate algorithm one can implement (but with no minimality guarantees) is the one of this paper:

[A fast and effective heuristic for the feedback arc set problem](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002001909390079O), by P. Eades, X. Lin, W.F. Smyth.

It is very easy to implement and works quite fast for large graphs (I tried it on a graph of 2.5 million edges and around 100 thousand nodes and broke all cycles in less than a minute).